How to find the collision between two object in three js, without using the bounding box
I have loaded a 3-D car model which is much similar to a 3D rectangle, But I can't find the exact collision. when the car turns, the bounding box size is increasing because of its cubic nature.So even through the car is not colliding with any other object, the collision becomes true, since the bounding box is colliding. If I am able to rotate the bounding box than that would work, but unfortunatly that option is not there.So is there any other possible solution
I have already tried the setFromObject method, also by setting the precise parameter to true, but that doesn't work.
This is the bounding box when the car is turning(means when I rotate the model along the y -axis)
This is the bounding box when it is straight. 
I don't want any gaps in between the model and the bounding box while turning.
this.car=await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>loader.load(
      modelPath,
      (gltf)=> {
        const car = gltf.scene;
        this.carBoundingBox= new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
        this.carBoundingBox.setFromObject(car,true);
      });

this.wall=await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>loader.load(
      modelPath,
      (gltf)=> {
        const wall = gltf.scene;
        this.wallBoundingBox= new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
        this.wallBoundingBox.setFromObject(wall,true);
      });
if(this.carBoundingBox.intersectsBox(this.wallBoundingBox))
    console.log("Collision detected")

